# Kinematics for dummies

Tags: reference-request, kinematics

I'm just beginning a course on Robotics and I've suddenly be pushed into a very unfamiliar world - Maths.

The following image shows an example of what I need to understand:
[image]

There's a lot more to that document.

I wonder if anyone can send me a link, or responses, which would teach a complete Maths novice the subject of **Kinematics**, please?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably a mix of things. It looks like rotational kinematics is what the chapter is about. http://www.physics.louisville.edu/cldavis/phys298/notes/rot_kin.html

The picture you are showing is just converting between Cartesian and polar coordinates. Point P and end of link is just Trigonometry.